# Using PG upsert for creating a toggle for "like" action on post

Tags: postgresql, toggle, upsert

I am trying to create a "Like" feature for posts.
In my web app, I have a table for users and one for posts. I have created a new table called `Like_posts` where I save which user liked which post.

One core constraint that each user can only like a post once. if the user clicks on the like button for a post which he/she already liked, then it will toggle/remove the like status.

The basic logic is :

If user clicks on like and
  if `like_posts` already contains a row with the `user_id` and `post_id`, remove the row (i.e. the user chose to dislike a previously liked post),
else add a new row with the `post_id` and `user_id`.

Currently i am firing 2 separate queries, first to check if the row exists and then my app decides if it should insert or remove. Considering that I expect "like" to be one of the most used features which mutate the db data, I really want to do it in one query.

I know I can do it via arrays (`liked_by` --> `user_id` in posts table) but I don't want to go that route. The unfurling and recreating of arrays using distinct data is not very performant and I really don't like using arrays or `jsonb` in PG (dislike the API).

I want to use something like an upsert, but from what I know, I can only do the "On Conflict (single column)" while I need "On conflict (both col1 and col2)".

What are my options and what would be a good way to design the toggling of "Like" button in my db?

Based on the excellent advice from @Laurenz Albe, I was able to improve the approach.
I now have a unique constraints on 2 columns as:

```
CREATE TABLE LIKE_POSTS (
    POST_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    USER_ID TEXT NOT NULL,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    DELETED_AT TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT "Unique_user_and_post_combo" PRIMARY KEY (POST_ID, USER_ID)
);
insert into like_posts (post_id, user_id) values (1,1);
```

I am still not sure how to do the delete action. Something like;

```
insert into like_posts (post_id, user_id) values (1,1) 
returning "ON"
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT Unique_user_and_post_combo
DO DELETE RETURNING "OFF";
```

Comment: You can have a unique or a primary key constraint on two columns, and you can use that constraint in the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: The problem with that would be that no other user will be able to like the post. In what I planned, these are valid rows `{row1 = {postid = 1, userid = 1}}, {row2={postid=1, userid=2}}`

Comment: I don't see the problem. `(postid, userid)` would be the natural primary key for the table. You are aware that a primary key can consist of several columns, right?

Comment: You could also have an int column and clicking adds 1, while the update query has a returning clause. Then you use mod % 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have got a primary key constraint, it should be simple to toggle the flag:

```
INSERT INTO like_posts (post_id, user_id, deleted_at)
   VALUES (1, 1, NULL) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT "Unique_user_and_post_combo"
DO UPDATE SET deleted_at = CASE WHEN deleted_at IS NULL
                                THEN current_timestamp
                           END;
```

This assumes that you use NULL in `deleted_at` to signify that the row is active.

I recommend that you do not use mixed case names (like you did for the constraint).